# Consequences for not using camel case in Kotlin file names

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

What would happen if I didn't use the camel case to name my Kotlin file? Would it cause performance issues or any other kind of technical issues?

> e.g. `SouthGeorgiaAndTheSouthSandwichIslands.kt` instead of its country code `SGS.kt`

Answer (score 1):

No technical issues, and no performance issues. The only drawback: it could be tricky to navigate and search classes. So, in general, it is better to stick to the Java convention, where a file name must be the same as a class name.

Answer (score 0):

There are no technical or performance issues.

Names are written for developers and not for machines, so you choose a name you (and your team) understand and know what is meant by it. Also it is good practice stick to the convetions of CamelCase as all Java/Kotlin developers are used to it and tooling like auto-completion and search in IDEs are optimised to support the camel case schema.